# RAM memory usage

Tags: ios, iphone, c, memory, ram

I need to get the ram memory usage not only for my app, but for the system, but I have a problem. I'm using host_statistics to get the free memory :

```
double freeMemory = 0.00;
vm_statistics_data_t vmStats;
mach_msg_type_number_t infoCount = HOST_VM_INFO_COUNT;
kern_return_t kernReturn = host_statistics(mach_host_self(), HOST_VM_INFO, (host_info_t)&vmStats, &infoCount);
if(kernReturn != KERN_SUCCESS) {
    return -1;
}
freeMemory = (vm_page_size * vmStats.free_count);
```

I know there is also task_info, but that function get info about the app, not about the all system. With host_statistics you can get info about wired, active, inactive and free memory, but if you sum all values, you don't get the total memory installed on the device. Why? Is there a way to get the real values about the memory management on iOS?

Comment: 1. It's most likely none of your business. 2. What would you use it for? Most of the time, almost all RAM is used because it is filled with apps that the user has launched and that are currently in the background, ready to be killed if more memory is needed.

Comment: This is not an answer or a constructive comment, I want to know why the system has this behavior and if there is a way to get the real informations about the memory usage. I need it for a feature for some apps.

Comment: There are a bunch of pages marked (according to libtop.c) as 'stolen', which means that simply adding up the numbers will never get you the total expected number of pages on system. Unless you're seeing something completely off-base this may account for the difference